# Passing HTML form into Javascript (ECMAScript) object

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Hi this is the code I've created it isn't working though:

```
  <P>Enter the details below to create a person object:</P>
    <label for ="fName" class="ui-input-text-label"><span style="font weight:bold;">First Name</span><span style="color: #82c341;"> </span></label>
    <input type="text" class="fName" name="fName" value="" placeholder="First Name">
    <label for ="sName" class="ui-input-text-label"><span style="font weight:bold;">Surname</span><span style="color: #82c341;"> </span></label>
    <input type="text" class="sName" name="sName" value="" placeholder="Surname">
    <label for ="age" class="ui-input-text-label"><span style="font weight:bold;">Age</span><span style="color: #82c341;"> </span></label>
    <input type="number" class="age" name="age" value="" placeholder="Age">
    <button class="submit" onClick="createPerson(this.form)">Submit</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/pages.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/util.js"></script>
<script>
    createPerson(){
        firstName=fName;
        surName=sName;
        age=this.age;
        console.log(firstName);
        console.log(surName);
        console.log(age);
        }
</script>
```

The console.log's are there simply as a test.

Comment: Forgot function keyword: `function createPerson() { .... }`.

Comment: Typically when you have code that "doesn't work", you should explain what it should do if it were working and any errors you get.

Comment: What does this have to do with ES6? Also, your function makes no sense. What are all these global variables doing there? Why doesn't it take a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, maybe:

```
<form name="personForm">
  <P>Enter the details below to create a person object:</P>

  <label for ="fName" class="ui-input-text-label"><span style="font weight:bold;">First Name</span><span style="color: #82c341;"> </span></label>
  <input type="text" class="fName" name="fName" value="" placeholder="First Name">
  <label for ="sName" class="ui-input-text-label"><span style="font weight:bold;">Surname</span><span style="color: #82c341;"> </span></label>
  <input type="text" class="sName" name="sName" value="" placeholder="Surname">
  <label for ="age" class="ui-input-text-label"><span style="font weight:bold;">Age</span><span style="color: #82c341;"> </span></label>
  <input type="number" class="age" name="age" value="" placeholder="Age">
  <button class="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
  var Person = function(firstName, surName, age){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.surName = surName;
    this.age = age;
  }

  document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var f = document.forms[0];
    var person = new Person(f.fName.value, f.sName.value, f.age.value);
    console.log(person);
  });
</script>
```

Not sure how much sense this makes, though. Depends on your context.